# How can ASP.NET's "Request Wait Time" be 0 when "Requests Queued" is consistently in the hundreds?

Tags: asp.net, performance-monitoring

I'm curious why Performance Monitor claims I always have a few hundred ASP.NET 3.5 requests "queued". The "Requests Queued" "ASP.NET v2.0.50727" performance counter is hovering in the few-hundred range despite the fact "Request Wait Time" is consistently 0. If each and every request never waits even a fraction of a millisecond, how could it be in the queue?

The "ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727" counters for "Requests In Application Queue" and "Request Wait Time" are always 0.

Answer (score 1):

In PerfMon, make sure your the .NET version for your counters is the same as the version your application uses.

It seems you are using .NET 3.5 for your application, but you're looking at .NET 2.0 counters.

Answer (score 0):

An old question for sure, but answered here: https://serverfault.com/a/579180

> The value of this counter is the number of milliseconds that the most
>   recent request spent waiting in the global queue. This does not
>   include any time the request spent waiting in the application queues.
>   The threshold for this counter is 1,000.