# Monitoring "Request Wait Time" in PerfMon

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, perfmon, load-testing, .net-4.0

A website I'm load testing is adding requests to the iis request queue. I can see the queue size getting bigger using the relevant performance counter:

- \ASP.NET\Requests Queued

However I'm trying to see the "Request wait time" and I've added the following Performance counters:

- \ASP.NET Apps v2.050727(__Total)\Request Wait Time
- \ASP.NET Apps v4.030319(__Total)\Request Wait Time
- \ASP.NET v4.030319\Request Wait Time
- \ASP.NET v2.050727\Request Wait Time

Which are all reporting 0 Average, 0 Min and 0 Max

Does anyone know how I can get the Request Wait Time on a ASP.NET V4 application running on IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 3):

Request Wait Time

The value of this counter is the number of milliseconds that the most recent request spent waiting in the global queue. This does not include any time the request spent waiting in the application queues.
The threshold for this counter is 1,000. The average request should spend 0 milliseconds waiting in the queue.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757130(v=ws.10).aspx